# Loop over multiple values stored in single column e.g [345 1234]

Tags: python, string, replace, split

I have a CSV file in which one column has stored two values at one position such as [345 1234] but sometimes there is no value such as [] or only one [456].
I write a script that works well for empty or single values but it failed for double values. I tried to split, replace space with **,**  but it gave an error because of an empty or single value. **How can I include these two values through the loop which can work for both empty and single value?**

**df file format is as below:**

20200423.GS022.mseed_597000,[ ],

20200423.GS022.mseed_600000,[ ],

20200423.GS022.mseed_603000,[424 1901],

20200423.GS022.mseed_606000,[2259],

```
#code for an empty or single value

with open('myfile.txt','w') as f:
for i in range(len(df)):
    itp = df.iloc[i, 1].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
    if itp != '':
        P=int(float(itp))/100
    else:
        P=0
```

**I got this error,**

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '424 1901'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the failure is you are converting `itp` to `float` however `424 1901` is a string with space in it and hence cannot be converted to `float`.
If `424` and `1901` are 2 different values you can use the below code:

```
with open('myfile.txt','w') as f:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        itp = df.iloc[i, 1].replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
        for val in itp.split():
            if val != '':
                P=int(float(val))/100
            else:
                P=0
            print (f'P: {P}')
```

However if both are a single value like `4241901` you can use the below code:

```
with open('myfile.txt','w') as f:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        itp = df.iloc[i, 1].replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(" ","")
        if itp != '':
            P=int(float(itp))/100
        else:
            P=0
```

Comment: Yes these are different values, but I need three conditions, P can only be zero if it is empty otherwise each number in itp will be divided by 100.

Comment: So that's what the code does. If val is empty, P is 0. The first code snippet is for you then as these are different values.

Comment: Ohh yes, it works but it does not print the value of P if it is equal to zero.

Comment: Cool.print was never a part of the code. Anyways have added the print statement as well in the edited code.

Comment: yes, It seems like after using split, it will not use empty value in the loop.